# Backbone Marionette event to get li element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following html code :

```
<ul id="selector">
   <li class="FIRST"><a>First</a></li>
   <li class="SECOND"><a>Second</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my backbone marionette snippet :

```
 ui: {
   element: "#selector li"
 }

 events: {
   'click @ui.element' : 'onChangeElement'
 }

 onChangeElement: function() {
   console.log(this.ui.element.attr('class'));
 }
```

This is always logging out "FIRST" instead of the class of li element selected.

Comment: The selector `#selector li` matches a range of elements... does the onChangeElement receive which `<li>` was clicked as it's argument? or an `event` object that you could use instead?

Comment: I am not sure, but I changed it as function(e) { console.log(e.target.attr('class'));} and it logged undefined. Can you please tell me how to pass the event? I am a beginner and I have no idea.

Comment: try `e.currentTarget`, instead of target. im not 100% sure how marionette works anymore, so I don't know if that function will receive an event.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Cory .. e.currentTarget worked perfectly